# assigning velocity to rigidbody doesn't do anything

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script attached to a mesh with a **kinematic,  rigid body with a convex mesh collider** that I'd like to move around. Here's what I call in my update function:

```c#
if (Input.GetKey(forwards)) {

        Debug.Log("forwards!!");

        //get current velocity in local space
        Vector3 localVel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(body.velocity);

        //alter so that forward component = speed
        localVel = new Vector3(localVel.x, localVel.y, linearSpeed);

        //convert back into world space and set to body
        Vector3 worldVel = transform.TransformDirection(localVel);
        body.velocity = worldVel;
    }
```

Other Info:

- `body` is a `Rigidbody` variable that I assign in `Start()` using `GetComponent<Rigidbody>();`
- `linearSpeed` is a `float` with value 1

I'm getting the `Debug.Log` output, but my mesh is not moving. Is there anything obvious I'm missing here? This is my first script for a 3D, as opposed to a 2D game.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what do you mean by moving around and do you want to use inertia when changing directions.

Comment: @Neven, I do want to use inertia. Let's say my character currently has a velocity in the x direction, but it is currently facing the 'z' direction, and I press 'forwards', I'd like for the character to have velocity in both the z and x directions. That's my reasoning behind this code

Comment: That said, the purpose of this question is to determine why the character's velocity doesn't change at all. Not that pointing out logic errors isn't welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c#
public float speed = 20; 
Rigidbody r;

void Start(){
    r = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> (); //Put's reference to local rigidbody into variable "r"
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    Vector3 direction = Vector3.zero; //set's current direction to none

    //Adds vectors in case that user is pressing the button
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) direction += Vector3.forward;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) direction -= Vector3.forward;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) direction += Vector3.right;
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) direction -= Vector3.right;

    //Normalizez direction (put's it's magnitude to 1) so object moves at same speeds in all directions
    r.AddForce (direction.normalized * speed); //Adds direction with magnitude of "speed" to rigidbody
}
```

Rigidbody **MUST** be attached to same GO as this script. This script uses world directions, because working with local directions is much harder (the object is rotating and changes directions rapidly, you can use it if you want just by replacing reference to Vector3 to transform like this:

```c#
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) direction += transform.forward;
```

Of course for all direction.

This is very **basic** way to move the object along it's local axises, to do it more better you need to write specific scripts for specific sets of objects, it all depends what kind of object are you moving and how you want to move it. (is it sphere, cube..., will it ever fly up, should it rotate....).

Answer (score 0):

If the RigidBody is Kinematic it is meant to be moved by means other than the physics system; animations, transform.position, etc. Make your rigid body non-kinematic and it should move when you set velocity.